# Building a function from a string of k letters that outputs a list of words from a Valid Word List, and finds the word with the highest scrabble score

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, scrabble

So I have a function that outputs all words from a string

However, I am struggling to integrate this into a list, currently, it outputs words in separate lists

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0 # Create score var
    for i in word: # Loop through given word
        total += score[i.lower()] #Lookup in dict, add total
    return total

def charCount(word): 
    dict = {} 
    for i in word: 
        dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
    return dict
  
  
def possible_words(lwords, charSet): 
    for word in lwords: 
        flag = 1
        chars = charCount(word) 
        for key in chars: 
            if key not in charSet: 
                flag = 0
            elif charSet.count(key) != chars[key]: 
                    flag = 0

        #for word in word_list:
        if flag == 1: 
            #word_value_dict = {}
            firstList = []
            #word_value_dict[word] = get_word_value(word, letter_values)
            firstList.append(word)
            #return word_value_dict
            print(scrabble_score(word), (word))
            print(firstList)
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    input = ['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'goal', 'boy', 'run'] 
    charSet = ['e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l', 'b'] 
    possible_words(input, charSet)
```

I also have a separate function that can find the word with the highest score from a list

```
def score(word):
    dic = {'D':2, 'C':2, 'L':2, 'P':2, 'B':3, 'N':3, 'F':4, 'G':4, 'H':4, 'V':4, 'J':5, 'Q':6, 'X':8, 'Y':8, 'Z':8}
    total = 0
    for char in word:
        total += dic.get(char.upper(), 0)
    return total
#return highest score
def best(lista):
    return max(lista, key=score)

best(['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'run'])
```

Output:

```
4 me
['me']
5 goal
['goal']
```

Desired output:
A list of all possible words

```
['me', 'goal']
```

OR
A dictionary (or similar structure) with possible words as keys and score as values

```
{'me':4, 'goal':5]
```

I need a way of returning a lsit from the first function, and combining the two to find the highest score in that list

**Part two:**

I need to extend this to calculate the highest score for all combinations of letter sets from letter length 2-8, and the number of combinations we can have to generate such a score

Comment: 1) You don't show function `scrabble_score`.  Is it different from function `score`?  2) Generally, it is discouraged to name variables the same as built-inin functions i.e. dict (in function charCount) and `input` as in `input = ['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'goal', 'boy', 'run'] `.

Comment: Setting of `firstList = []` and `firstList.append(word)` in the multiple places is confusing.  Code comments would help to follow your logic.

Comment: Thanks for this Darryl, removed the first instance

Comment: @Hamster--function `scrabble_score` is missing.  Is this the same as function `score`?  If so pssible_words gives me a different result than your post.  I get: `0 me
['me']
6 goal
['goal']`

Comment: Yeah they are two different functions but do different things. I referred to scrabble_score but included score in my post, apologies

They both seem to work ok, do you know how I could integrate the returned words into a single list?

Comment: @Hamster--could you add the code for `scrabble_score` so I will have working code?  Since there are no comments I could use working code to see what the functions should do.

Comment: Hi Darryl, 

Function is at the top of the question and below

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0 # Create score var
    for i in word: # Loop through given word
        total += score[i.lower()] #Lookup in dict, add total
    return total

Comment: 1) Can you show your desired output, and 2) note: funciton `scrabble_score` does not compile since score is a funciton, line `total += score[i.lower()]` should be `total += score(i.lower()])`.

Comment: Added desired output, ideally a list of possible words

I feel like we've done the hard work, just need to apply this finishing touch

Comment: @Hamster--a simple change allows a dictionary output, but I get the result `{'me': 0, 'goal': 6}`.  Are you sure that dictionary `{'me':4, 'goal':5]` is the correct result?

Comment: @Hamster--since dic in function `score` does not have letters 'M" or 'E', the score for the word 'me' should be 0, but you show 4.  This seems incorrect.